# debugging javascript -- and gigantic error lists in standard libraries

Tags: javascript, debugging, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

One of the persistent problems I have when debugging javascript is that should the compiler find an error and put it on the console, the error tends to get lost. The reason being that most of the standard libraries have hundreds of console errors in standard firebug consoles. I use jQuery, bootstrap and Angular and the all produce lots and lots of noise in the console window, that makes it hard to find the real errors.
When I compile code I always clear out ALL warnings so that errors are more evident. But there doesn't seem an easy way to do this in JavaScript.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I've used all these libraries and I don't see any errors generated by them in the console. Could it not be an error from your code that's triggering errors in the libraries? If you use console.trace() or chromes console then you can see where errors originate rather than where they occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you think instead of a flat view, an `indented view` of console logs might help you, you can try using `console.group("Group Name")` to start a new indentation block and `console.groupEnd()` to close it.
You can create such indented groups for different phases/interactions in your code, which might make it a little easier to read the logs as they will be nested under the `"Group Name"` used to create the group.